# Mysql PHP , How to select data that start with a specific carachter

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `cities`:

```
+----+--------+
| id | zip    | 
+----+--------+
|  1 | 07500  | 
|  2 | 07501  | 
|  3 | 75000  | 
|  4 | 75001  | 
|  5 | 75002  | 
+----+--------+
```

And I need to select data where the `field zip` start with `750`, so I've tried :

```
SELECT FROM cities WHERE ZIP LIKE '%750%'
```

But this returns me all data in the table that contain `750` and this isn't normal. How could I tell my query to select data that start with `750` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do this query:

```
SELECT FROM cities WHERE ZIP LIKE '750%'
```

**Explanation**

`%` is a special MySQL character that means any character, empty string or group of characters.

**Examples:**

```
LIKE '%a%' -- matches: a, ant, track | any string that contains a in any location
LIKE 'a%'  -- matches: a, ant        | strings that start with a
LIKE '%a'  -- matches: a, data       | strings that end with a
```

Answer (score 6):

This should make the magic:

```
SELECT FROM cities WHERE ZIP LIKE '750%'
```

% at begin means any thing before.

Answer (score 2):

```
LIKE '750%'
```

should do the trick

if your string contains `'%'` character than you would need to use `\%`